# JS/html5 - Copying a <select> and check it again

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, drop-down-menu

Before I start explaining my problem, I want to apologize for my english.

So, I have a basic html code that look like this :

```
  <body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="taskList">
    <div id="firstTask">

      <!-- I just put two select form side to side with css, it's working.
      There is the display I want. The values of my select are in my json file.
      There is no problem here. -->

          <select id="selectedTask" 
              class="form-control"
              ng-model="taskValue"
              ng-options="task.type for task in tasks.data.task"
              ng-change="taskType=(tasks.data.task)[0].type">
            <option value="">Choose a task</option>
          </select>
        <select id="selectedProject"
            class="form-control"
            ng-model="projectValue"
            ng-options="project.type for project in tasks.data.project"
            ng-change="projectType=(tasks.data.project)[0].type">
          <option value="">Project</option>
        </select>

            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="checkValues()">OK</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

 <button id="addTask" onclick="newTask()">Click here to add a new task!</button>
```

There is the function which check the values :

```
function checkValues()
{
  var task = document.getElementById("selectedTask");
  var project = document.getElementById("selectedProject");

  var taskValue = task.options[task.selectedIndex].value;
  var projectValue = project.options[project.selectedIndex].value;

  var buttonAdd = document.getElementById("addTask");

  if (taskValue === "" projectValue === "") {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Complete them all please.";
    buttonAdd.disabled = true;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "It has been saved.";
    buttonAdd.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

And here the function which add a new div task into "container" :

```
function newTask(){

var entireList = document.getElementById("container");
var buttonAdd = document.getElementById("addTask");

buttonAdd.disabled = true;
var getTask = document.getElementById("taskList").cloneNode(true);
var addTask = document.getElementById("taskList").parentNode.appendChild(getTask);
}
```

When the user click on the button "add a new task" I clone the div "firstTask" into "taskList" so there are 2 lines of select now, that is what I want. But when I clone it, the select take the same options of the first div "firstTask" and then the checkValue Button only check the first div no matter what I choose in the second div I just cloned.

Thanks guys for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you clone, you clone the same id, so the cloned element has the same id as the original element. Remember, id must be unique.

To solve your problem, create a variable (`int` value) that increase every time you click the button, and concat it to your cloned `id`.

Comment: Yeah, I know but the thing is that I want exactly the same div juste below the first when I click on "add a new task".

Comment: For some reasons I added a class next to the id="taskList" and incremented it as you said. But how can I do to make my checkValues() fonction general? :o

I thought of passing the class of my div into paremeters of the function but I don't figure out how I can do it.

Comment: Do not use inline javascript event, use it into your javascript, and it will be easy to manipulate it

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally achieved what I wanted to do, here the final code :

```
  <div id="container">
    <div id="taskList" class="taskList">
      <div class="firstTask">
        <select
          class="form-control selectedTask"
          ng-model="taskValue"
          ng-options="task.type for task in tasks.data.task"
          ng-change="taskType=(tasks.data.task)[0].type">
          <option value="">Choose a task</option>
      </select>
      <select
          class="form-control selectedProject"
          ng-model="projectValue"
          ng-options="project.type for project in tasks.data.project"
          ng-change="projectType=(tasks.data.project)[0].type">
          <option value="">Project</option>
      </select>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="checkValues()">OK</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="addTask" onclick="newTask()">Add a new task!</button>
```

There is the function which check the values :

```
  function checkValues()
  {
    if (i != 0) {
      var a = "taskList";
      var b = i;
      var string = a.concat(b);
      var test = document.getElementsByClassName(string)[0];
    }
    else {
      var test = document.getElementsByClassName("taskList")[0];
    }
    var task = test.getElementsByClassName("selectedTask")[0];
    var project = test.getElementsByClassName("selectedProject")[0];

    var taskValue = task.options[task.selectedIndex].value;
    var projectValue = project.options[project.selectedIndex].value;

    var buttonAdd = document.getElementById("addTask");

    if (taskValue === "" || projectValue === "") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Complete them all please.";
      buttonAdd.disabled = true;
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "It has been saved.";
      buttonAdd.disabled = false;
    }
  }
```

And here the function which add a new div task into "tasklist" :

```
  var i = 0;
  function newTask(){

  var entireList = document.getElementById("container");
  var buttonAdd = document.getElementById("addTask");

  buttonAdd.disabled = true;
  if (i == 0) {
    ++i;
    var getTask = document.getElementsByClassName("taskList")[0].cloneNode(true);
    var addTask = document.getElementsByClassName("taskList")[0].parentNode.appendChild(getTask);
    addTask.className = "taskList" + i;
  }
  else {
    var a = "taskList";
    var b = i;
    var string = a.concat(b);
    var getTask = document.getElementsByClassName(string)[0].cloneNode(true);
    var addTask = document.getElementsByClassName(string)[0].parentNode.appendChild(getTask);
    i++;
    addTask.className = "taskList" + i;
  }
```

So yeah I know my variable's name aren't explicit, I'll change it.
Thank you for helping me ! And if you have any suggestions to improve my code, just tell me please, thanks ;)